# Time dependent workflow firing always

Tags: time-dependent-workflow

I have time dependent workflow on the opportunity which should send an email 30 days before the opportunity close date. But the email alert is being sent when ever an opportunity is created with a close date of next week. Let me  know what the issue could be. Below are screenshots of the time dependent workflow:-

I am using the below trigger condition,

30 Days before opportunity close date.

Comment: From what you are saying it sounds the workflow is behaving as expected since the close date is next week which is under 30 days. Make sense?

Answer (score 4):

This is working as designed.

If the close date is 2 weeks from today and the WFR is supposed to send an alert 30 days before, it will send immediately as it is < 30 days before the close date.

To prevent it you will have to exclude those opportunities in your criteria

Comment: This behavior is only until the saleforce.com developers figure out how to send data in to the past reliably without creating paradoxes.

Comment: @sfdcfox - One would think there could be an option with TimeBased WFR to exclude inserted records that cause an execution date in the past.